# Combining 3 strings in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that filters data by user, date range and specific value for a column, depending if checkbox is ticked or not, as below;

```
    strWhere = " WHERE [user] in (" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & ") And [Month] Between [forms]![frm_user]![txtStartDate] And [forms]![frm_user]![txtEndDate]"

    If Me!checkbox = True Then
        strtcheck = " (Satified Vs Dissatisfied Like Dissatisfied) "
    End If

    strSql = strSql & strwhere & strtcheck
```

So what I want and I can't get it to work is, if Me!checkbox is true, than the Satified Vs Dissatisfied must be equal to Dissatisfied and then I want to pass it to the strSql, however when i run it in Access it doesn't work, can someone help?

Comment: some quotes appear to be missing in your synthesized where clause. try `strWhere = " WHERE [user] in ('" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "') And [Month] Between [forms]![frm_user]![txtStartDate] And [forms]![frm_user]![txtEndDate]"`. what do the `Vs` operator in `strtcheck` mean? are `Satisfied`, `Dissatisfied` table attributes, form attributes or literals? the `like` operator only makes sense when used together with the sql wildcard (`%`). if you append `strtcheck` to the partial where clause, you forgot the operator (`AND`?). what's the content of `strIN`?.

Comment: the vs its the name of a column "Satified Vs Dissatisfied"

Comment: ok, just saw it in hansup's answer (which together with single quotes around the literal in the first part of the where clause should do the trick).

Answer (score 1):

If your string is intended to include a `WHERE` condition for a field named *Satified Vs Dissatisfied*, enclose the field name in square brackets.  And enclose the string you compare to the field in quotes.

```vb
strtcheck = " ([Satified Vs Dissatisfied] Like 'Dissatisfied') "
```

Actually that condition doesn't use pattern matching, so you could just use `=` instead of `Like`.

```vb
strtcheck = " ([Satified Vs Dissatisfied] = 'Dissatisfied') "
```

Also you likely need to include SQL `AND` to combine that condition with the other `WHERE` conditions.

```vb
strtcheck = " AND ([Satified Vs Dissatisfied] = 'Dissatisfied') "
```

Comment: thanks, but my real issue is with strSql = strSql & strwhere & strtcheck, it doesn't work

Comment: doesn't contain anything, it's empty. Can I combine 3 strings like shown above?

Comment: @qebas: you need to append `strtcheck` with an operator (`AND` i guess) to get a syntacticaly valid where clause. turn `strtcheck = " (Satified Vs Dissatisfied Like Dissatisfied) "` into `strtcheck = " AND ([Satified Vs Dissatisfied] = 'Dissatisfied') "`. and make sure that you have no spelling error ( `Sati_s_fied` ) in your column name.

Comment: @collapsar Good point, thanks.  I added that to my answer.  However I can't understand why `strSql` is empty.